# How to pass an url as parameter of include

Tags: django, django-templates

I would like to know how I can pass url as parameter of an include in django template.

I have in my code, a HTML file that is used to create a button. So when want to add this button I just include it. Problem is that 1 of the parameters is URL, and for now I have not found other solution than putting text url.

SO what I have this:

```
{% include "button.html" with title="title" link="/new-event/" %}
```

and I would have to have something like:

```
{% include "button.html" with title="title" link={% url myview.view%} %}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you would have to assign the url to a variable that is added to the context in order to use it in an include tag.

Example:

**view:**

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def your_view(request):
    url = reverse('the_url_name_to_reverse', args=[], kwargs={})
    return render(request, 'the-template.html', {'url': url})
```

**template:**

```
{% include "button.html" with title="title" link=url %}
```

If it's a value you need in every template, you might consider adding a context processor to add the reversed url value to the context

Comment: Thanks for your response. In fact it was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 22):

Have you tried this syntax:

```
{% url 'some-url-name' arg arg2 as the_url %}
{% include "button.html" with title="title" link=the_url %}
```

Comment: It's concise, it works, and does not require me to write any extra code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Some might find this solution more suitable:

first create a filter

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
@register.filter()
def rev(value):
    return reverse(value)
```

then use it in the template like this

```
{% include "button.html" with title="title" link="myview.view"|rev %}
```

Comment: Love it; it avoids to fill up the view with unnecessary code.